# How can I make a window take over the entire screen? MacOS SwiftUI

Tags: swift

How can I make a window that is the fullscreen of the MacOS screen that goes over the menuBar, and goes over the applications at the bottom. I saw functions like 'setMenuBarVisible'; however this does not work in SwiftUI. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419527-togglefullscreen

Comment: how would I implement an AppKit function with SwiftUI though. That's what I'm most confused about

Answer (score 1):

This code will make your app toggle fullscreen on launch.

```
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let window = NSApplication.shared.windows.last {
                            window.toggleFullScreen(nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but.